# How to get feature data by passing lat/long value to FeatureServer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have created a feature layer and deployed it as a service on ArcGIS Online? Is there any way to pass lat/long values as query parameters and get respective feature layer details?

Comment: I tried adding featureService as feature layer over a basemap. Now I want to plot a point on the map and if the point falls on the feature layer, I want to get the feature layer detail. Is it possible to get details of feature layer based on the coordinate using arcgis javascript api?

Comment: Can you edit your Question to revise it with these details, please ?  That keeps it easy to read for potential answerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish a layer as a Feature service, it is served through a Rest API; The Rest API for a feature Service usually supports the [Query Operation](https://services.arcgis.com/help/index.html?fsServiceQuery.html).

You can pass in your point coordinates and do a spatial query, to get the resulting features.

Unfortunately, I currently don't have an ArcGIS Online Account, so I can't give you a running example.

I can give you a simple example of a Query Task which return the polygon that contains the input point. Please see [this query](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_1990-2000_Population_Change/MapServer/4/query?text=&geometry=-100,%2038&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelWithin&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=4326&outFields=%2a&f=html) on the US States layer. It will return that states, that contains the point with latitude 38N and longitude 100 W

Comment: Thanks for reply Devdatta, this is where I got stuck like what sould be the query parameters. As the examples I have seen have "where" clause that works on point data but the feature layer I have, contains polygon and my query should return the polygon details where the point coordinate fall. It would be vey useful if you could help me with the query. Thanks

Comment: @user2011364: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Devdatta, it worked. That's what I was looking for.